# OpenCV Haartraining does not finish forever

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, adaboost, training-data

This is the first time I use haartraining of opencv.

Just for practice, I used 35 positive images and 45 negative images.

But when I try to train from data, It does not finish forever,

Even when parameters are extremely adjusted.

(min hit rate = 0.001, max false alarm rate = 0.999

I don't think it would take a lot of time because of this extreme values)

What must be wrong in my experiment?

Here is my command and parameters.

```
$opencv_haartraining -data Training -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.dat -nstages 2 -nsplits     2 -minhitrate 0.001 -maxfalsealarm 0.999 -npos 30 -nneg 40 -w 20 -h 20 -nonsym -mem 512 -mode      ALL -minpos 10
```

And the result.

```
Data dir name: Training
Vec file name: samples.vec
BG  file name: negatives.dat, is a vecfile: no
Num pos: 30
Num neg: 40
Num stages: 2
Num splits: 2 (tree as weak classifier)
Mem: 512 MB
Symmetric: FALSE
Min hit rate: 0.001000
Max false alarm rate: 0.999000
Weight trimming: 0.950000
Equal weights: FALSE
Mode: ALL
Width: 20
Height: 20
Applied boosting algorithm: GAB
Error (valid only for Discrete and Real AdaBoost): misclass
Max number of splits in tree cascade: 0
Min number of positive samples per cluster: 10
Required leaf false alarm rate: 0.998001
Stage 0 loaded
Stage 1 loaded
Stage 2 loaded
Stage 3 loaded
Stage 4 loaded

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4

Number of features used : 125199

Parent node: 4

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 30 32 0.937500
```

Comment: It really takes long time. Try large number of positive(1000) and negative(900) samples with lower width(15) and height(15).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am I correct in thinking that you are using OpenCV_Haartraining?

If so this is a deprecated app and you should use opencv_traincascades.

This will

```
- A. Speed up the time taken to classify 
 - B. Have better support
```

See these links for further reading
 [Training Vs TrainCascade](http://answers.opencv.org/question/757/haartraining-vs-traincascade-object-detection/) and [TrainCascade Wiki](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html).

EDIT:

also, change your min hit rate and maxFalseAlarm rate.

I would suggest using something like 0.4 & 0.95 to get going.

reason for this is that it will take forever for it to hit 0.999 & 0.0001 if ever.

Comment: i was using opencv_haartraining

Comment: How do I distinguish between the program being in an infinite loop and proceeding?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. Referring to [this tutorial](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) and my own experience, it's normal the training takes couple of days even up to a week. Quoting from the tutorial:

> FYI: I recommend you to work haartrainig with something different
>   concurrently because you have to wait so many days during training (it
>   would possibly take one week). I typically experimented as 1. run
>   haartraining on Friday 2. forget about it completely 3. see results on
>   next Friday 4. run another haartraining (loop).

Comment: How do I distinguish between the program being in an infinite loop and proceeding?